# Display a list with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var application = angular.module('Application');

  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.result = "Start here ...";

    $http.get('api/images').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.images = data;
        $scope.result = "Everything is ok";
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = "Something went wrong";
      });

  });
</script>

<div ng-app="Application" ng-controller="ImageControler">

  <p>{{result}}</p>
  <div ng-repeat='image in images'>
    <span>{{image.votes}}</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I get on the rendered HTML page is {{result}} and {{image.votes}} like Angular was not working ... I also checked the API and it is not called ...

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the console, I suspect your module definition is invalid, you're missing the dependencies array for one, var application = angular.module('Application',[]);

Comment: I added that and not the {{image.votes}} part disappears, the API is not called, and the {{result}} appears instead if its string. Any idea?

Comment: Check if you get any data in the data object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have spelling mistake in `<div ng-app="Application" ng-controller="ImageControler">`

Controller with 2 L's